# Create a function that calls a sum given specified date

Tags: python, function, date, for-loop

I am trying to build a function which takes in a specified date (2020 -08-01), checks the categorical criteria (y / n) and if true, outputs the sum or count of the true categorical criteria for the specified date.

This is what I have tried but have been unsuccessful. I don't know how call the date format as a function.

```
def hospital_admit(date):
   #######
    #retruns the number of patients admitted on a specified day
   #######
    #for number of patient entries on specified date
    for num in date:
        #check if patient was admitted to hospital 
        if hosp_yn == True:
            # the number is equal to the sum of patients admitted to hospital on the specified date 
            num = sum(hosp_yn)
    return num
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your **date** variable is a `datetime` object.
If not, take a look at [python datetime model](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html)

If so, first change the name so it wont collides with `datetime.date` for example, or some other obvious functions.

Regarding your question - what about: `yourdatetime.date() == person_arrival_date.date()`